# Extract text between slashes which contain '='

Tags: regex, scala

I want a regex to extract the text between slashes which contain an equals '='

`data/xx/yy/zz/date=20190506/xxx.json`

-> `date=20190506`

Comment: Please post the code that fails for you, to see what the programming issue is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi, thanks for your suggestion, but a regex is universal

Comment: No, regex is not universal. You mentioned Scala, so you need it to be Java regex engine compatible. What is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex not needed.

```
val str = "data/x=x/yy/zz/date=20190506/xxx.json"  //example string (modified)

str.split("/").filter(_.contains('='))
//res0: Array[String] = Array(x=x, date=20190506)
```